# Change minutes dynamically in CronTab on Azure DevOps with Pipeline Variable

Tags: azure-devops, cron, yaml, azure-pipelines, azure-yaml-pipelines

I have a yaml pipeline where I would like to set the CRON minutes with a Variable Pipeline to avoid making commits and pull requests.

When I try to do something like this I get syntax errors:

```yaml
schedules:
- cron: "*/$(PipelineVariable) * * * *"
  displayName: Daily midnight build
```

It doesn't work inside the string - this is the error I get:

> Encountered error(s) while parsing pipeline YAML: /execution.yaml (Line: 8, Col: 4):
> Error while validating cron input. Improperly formed cron syntax: '*/$(Minutes) * * * *'.

And it doesn't work outside either.

> /execution.yaml (Line: 8, Col: 4):
> Error while validating cron input. Improperly formed cron syntax: '$(CronTab)'.

Why doesn't it accept the syntax from a Pipeline variable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following documentation has mentioned "***You cannot use pipeline variables when specifying schedules.***":

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/scheduled-triggers?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml

[image]

You may submit a suggestion at website below:

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/post.html?space=21

Comment: Do you mean we can't pass cron expressions from pipeline variables?